# Using importance sampling to simulate the mean of a normal distribution truncated to interval [0,1]

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, sampling, simulation

So in these [notes](http://people.hss.caltech.edu/~mshum/gradio/simulation.pdf) it says that importance sampling is:
$$\int_F sf(s)ds = \int_G s \frac{f(s)}{g(s)}g(s)ds$$

And then it proceeds to give the following example:

---

[image]

---

In this example, if we draw from $f(x)$, are we effectively drawing from the truncated standard normal distribution? Also, can someone explain why it says that $g(x)=1$ if we draw $x$ from $U[0,1]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a 'toy' example because it is easier and better to do
numerical integration, roughly as used to make printed normal tables,
to get the correct answer. However, it is a nice simple example to
get you acquainted with acceptance sampling.

**Numerical integration (no simulation).** So at the start, let's find the correct answer to your problem with
numerical integration. In R statistical software, this can be done
as follows:

```
integrand = function(x){x*dnorm(x)/diff(pnorm(c(0,1)))}
# 'dnorm' is std normal PDF;  'pnorm' is std normal CDF
integrate(integrand, 0, 1)
0.4598622 with absolute error < 5.1e-15
```

My 'function' is $xK\varphi(x),$ where $1/K = \int_0^1 \varphi(x)\,dx$
and $\varphi$ denotes the standard normal density.
So for $X$ distributed according to your truncated normal distribution
with denisty $\varphi^*(x),$ for $x \in (0,1)$ and $0$ otherwise,
we have $E(X) = \int_0^1 x\varphi^*(s)\,dx \approx 0.4599.$ [Reality check: A sketch
should convince you that the answer must be in $(0,1)$ and slightly below $1/2.$]

**Brute force simulation.** In R, the 'brute force' simulation method you mention amounts to the following:

```
x = rnorm(10^6)          #'rnorm' samples from std normal
mean(x[x > 0 & x < 1])
## 0.4598828
```

This is indeed an inefficient method because we are averaging over only
fewer than 341,000 out of the one million sampled values of `x`. (This inefficiency  is to
be anticipated, because $1/K = P(0 < Z < 1) = .3413,$ where 
$Z \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$ ) I got a good answer because I used
a million iterations, which would have been an unthinkable extravagance
only a few years ago.

```
sum(x > 0 & x < 1)
## 340532
```

**Importance sampling.**  In answer to one of your questions: 
$g(x) = 1,$ for $x \in (0,1)$ because
that is the PDF of $\textsf{Unif}(0,1).$

Now, consider the equation
$$\int_0^1 xf(x)\,dx = \int_0^1 x\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}g(x)\,dx = \int_0^1 xw(x)g(x)\,dx
= \int_0^1 xw(x)\,dx,$$
where $w(x) = f(x)/g(x).$ Here $f(x) = \varphi^*(x)$ above.
R code for the desired mean below uses all one million values sampled
from $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1).$

```
K = 1/diff(pnorm(c(0,1)))  
u = runif(10^6)
K*mean(u*dnorm(u))
## 0.4599921
```

Comment: Ah, so we are effectively drawing numbers between 0 and 1 by using a uniform distribution right?

Comment: Yes, 'runif` is R-speak for sampling from a uniform distribution, and parameters 0 and 1 are the defaults.

Comment: @BruceET In your importance sampling example, there is no K in your equation, but it shows in your code, where does it come from?

Answer (score 1):

Importance sampling means: to compute an average of $h$ against the pdf $f$, draw samples from the pdf $g$, and average $\frac{h f}{g}$. The goal is to choose $g$ which is nearly directly proportional to $hf$, so that $\frac{hf}{g}$ is nearly constant (and therefore has small variance). On the other hand, if $hf$ has one sign and you could draw directly from $g=C hf$, then you would already know what the integral of $hf$ was: it would just be $1/C$. So you would already be done. So there is a compromise to be made.

In the problem you are looking at, if you were drawing from $f$, then yes you would be drawing from the truncated normal distribution. When you are drawing from $g$, the pdf of $U[0,1]$, that pdf is just $1$ on $(0,1)$ and zero elsewhere, by the definition of the uniform distribution.